# How to sort an array of strings containing numbers and letters in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings, each element contains two or three numbers, one space and one letter.

```
array = [ "293 C",
 "401 B","421 B","428 B","439 B","315 C","529 B","560 B","566 B",
 "567 B","616 B","39 C","28 C","30 C","698 B","719 B","722 B",
 "640 B","786 B","645 B","236 B","255 B","442 C","446 C","477 C",
 "368 C","381 C","399 C","406 C","504 C","505 C","515 C","116 C",
 "138 C","147 C","174 C"]
```

What I need as a result is something like this.

```
["236 B","255 B","401 B","421 B","428 B","439 B","529 B","560 B",
"566 B","567 B","616 B","640 B","645 B","698 B","719 B","722 B",
"786 B","28 C","30 C", "39 C","116 C","138 C","147 C","174 C", "293 C",
"315 C", "368 C", "381 C","399 C","406 C","442 C","446 C",
"477 C","504 C","505 C","515 C"]
```

In other words, I need to sort the list of strings using the letter suffix as the major sort key, and the integer value of the digit prefix as the minor key.

I've tried with sort_by method, but it only allows me to sort the array by the letter (if I split each element first)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.sort_by { |item|
  number, letter = *item.split
  [letter, number.to_i]
}
```

Arrays compare as their first element; in case an element is equal, next element is compared.

Comment: splat is redundant.

Comment: @mudasobwa: It is. And I am inconsistent in applying it. But the rule that autosplats arrays in multiple assignments is probably the one part of Ruby that I truly dislike.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
array.sort_by {|s| [s[/[a-zA-Z]+/], s.to_i]}

                        ^                      grab the letter or letters and the end
                                      ^        convert the digits at the front
```

Or, as point out in comments, it is better not to use a latin based character class.

You can do:

```
array.sort_by { |s| [s[s.index(/[\t ]\S/)+1..-1], s.to_i] }

                                 ^       tab, space followed by not a space
```

Or,

```
array.sort_by { |s| [s[/[^\d\t ]+/], s.to_i] }

                            ^             skip digits and spaces -- the rest
```

Or,

```
array.sort_by { |s| [s[/\p{L}+/], s.to_i] }

                           ^ code point in the category "letter".
```

Comment: ...or `{ |s| [s[/\D+/], s.to_i] }`.

Comment: `s[/\D+/]` picks up leading spaces before the letters. If there ever where 'noise' in the input data, such as an inconsistent number of spaces between the two columns, it would change the sort. `s[s.index(/\s\S/)+1..-1]` probably better.

Comment: @dawg well, it’s a naïve approach to think that letters means latin. I could bring more examples on the table if we were tête-à-tête, но вокруг, к сожалению, много наблюдателей. :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Agreed. The form `s[s.index(/\s\S/)+1..-1]` does not suffer that issue tho. Thanks

Comment: `\p{L}` should do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am not sure if you are aware of this is translated back as “look for better salary” :)

Comment: Google translate say Следуйте за деньгами => *Follow the money*

Comment: @mudasobwa, my intent was dawg's finding and Bob Mueller's mantra.

Comment: @dawg, that's a good point about the weakness of the regex I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
array.sort_by { |e| [e[-1], e.to_i] }
```

Comment: How is this answer different compared to the one by @Amadan?

Comment: @mudasobwa Not much, only differs in how the array is formed; and it can be used in a single line without the need of  `;` (BTW, I wasn't aware of Amadan's answer while posting).

Answer (score 1):

```
array.sort_by { |s| s[-1] << s[/\d+/].rjust(3, '0') }
  #=> ["236 B", "255 B", "401 B",..., "722 B", "786 B",
  #     "28 C",  "30 C",  "39 C",..., "505 C", "515 C"]
```

Note:

```
array.map { |s| s[-1] << s[/\d+/].rjust(3, '0') }.sort
  #=> ["B236", "B255", "B401",..., "B722", "B786",
  #    "C028", "C030", "C039",..., "C505", "C515"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort_by { |e| e.split.reverse.map { |s| s.to_i(36) } }
```